# Como vejo os valores dos registradores no disassembly de um 'olá mundo'?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, clang

Eu sei que para ver o código assembly de um arquivo objeto gerado a partir de um código C, podemos utilizar o objdump da seguinte maneira

`objdump -d arquivo.obj`

No meu caso, dropa o seguinte código assembly na tela:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   4:   e1a0b00d        mov     fp, sp
   8:   e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
   c:   e3000000        movw    r0, #0
  10:   e58d0004        str     r0, [sp, #4]
  14:   e59f0010        ldr     r0, [pc, #16]   @ 2c <main+0x2c>
  18:   e08f0000        add     r0, pc, r0
  1c:   ebfffffe        bl      0 <printf>
  20:   e3000000        movw    r0, #0
  24:   e1a0d00b        mov     sp, fp
  28:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
  2c:   0000000c        .word   0x0000000c
```

Mas como eu acesso os valores dos registradores?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, objdump se trata de um programa que realiza a leitura do código binário de um objeto. De forma simplificada, podemos entender que cada linha é um comando para o processador executar.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html

Não é possível olhar o valor dos registradores, pois o programa não está sendo executado, e os registradores não estão computando os valores informados no código.

Para sabermos o valor dos registradores, é necessário utilizar uma técnica de Análise Dinâmica, na qual analisamos o comportamento do programa enquanto o mesmo está em execução. Já a análise de binário por meio do objdump se trata de uma Análise Estática.
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/what-is-the-difference-between-static-disassembly-and-dynamic-disassembly

Para chegar no seu objetivo, estude e pesquise sobre análises dinâmicas, como  o debugging. Dê uma olhada no WinDBG.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).